# excel - sumifs formula with range on criteria

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, criteria, sumifs

I have these data

```
    A    B    C       D
1  lvl1 lvl2 lvl3    value
2  1    1.1  1.1.1   3
3  1    1.1  1.1.2   2
4  1    1.2  1.1.3   7
5  2    2.1  2.1.1   2
6  2    2.1  2.1.2   3
```

and i want the output of the formula to be like this

```
7 Type    LEVEL    value
8  1      level1   12
9  1.1    level2   5
10 1.2    level2   7
11 2      level1   5
12 2.1.1  level3   2
```

I have already implemented this request with sumifs (cause i have more than one criteria in the original case) by putting in "criteria range" nested if

```
sumifs(D2:D6,IF(B8="level1",A2:A6),IF(B8="level2",B2:B6),IF(B8="level3",C2:C6))))
```

Is there any other way (perhaps with index & match?) to have the same result?

Answer (score 1):

If your Levels are exactly the same name as your column headers (so `lvl1` instead of `level1`), then you can use this formula in cell C8 and copied down:

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$6,INDEX($A$2:$C$6,0,MATCH(B8,$A$1:$C$1,0)),A8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put these formulas into H2:I2.

```
="level"&LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2, ".", ""))+1
=SUMIFS(D:D, INDEX(A:C, 0, LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2, ".", ""))+1), G2)
```

Fill down.

[image]